# Speed up CSV loading with datatools package?

Tags: datatool, csv, performance

I am using the `datatool` package to read some CSV files. I've used the `csvsimple` package before, which I finally managed to break by adding more and more requirements to the mix. Now I'd like to switch to the `datatool` package, load the "databases" once and use them repeatedly. The problem is: Loading the files takes forever. The files have about 1000 lines each with 13, 6 and 8 columns respectively, and loading the first file alone takes way more than five minutes. If I turn on verbose logging of the `datatool` package, I can see the load process getting slower and slower the more data is read. Is this just the way it is (which would mean I'll have to find another alternative) or can I do anything to speed up the loading process?

Comment: Maybe file a bug report against datatool? I also have performance issues with datatool - see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225438/3406.

Comment: Can you provide code for a sample usage?  It is one thing to confirm the problem with the present approach, but the development of alternatives generally requires a more specific knowledge of the application.

Answer (score 5):

[`csvsimple`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple) is described as a lightweight tool that doesn't support sorting or data storage, whereas [`datatool`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool) is a heavyweight package that supports both sorting and storage, and it's the extra functionality that makes `datatool` slower than `csvsimple`.

The issue basically comes down to the fact that although TeX is Turing complete it's a document formatting language rather than a computer programming language and it doesn't have array-like structures in which to conveniently store multi-dimensional data. In most languages you can do something like `float[][] array = new float[m][n]` and then access an entry using something like `array[i][j]` and set the value for an entry using something like `array[i][j] =`*value*.

However in TeX, there are essentially two ways of storing data: either in a macro or in a register. The first version of `datatool` used a macro for storage, but the internal structure was changed in `datatool` version 2.0 thanks to Morten Høgholm who provided a much better method of storing the data within a token register. This significantly improved the data lookup, but since the entire database is stored within a single token register, *changing* the data (rather than a simple lookup) requires splitting up the contents of the register around the entry that needs changing and then recombining the whole thing with the new value and resetting the contents of the register. When loading a database from a CSV file, this needs to be done for every cell in the database. (Other things are done as well, such as determining the data type for the given column.)

The `verbose` mode can also add to the load time. This is off by default, but for big databases without the `verbose` mode it can look as though nothing's happening.

Here's an example document that simply loads data from a file called `entries.csv`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddb{entries}{entries.csv}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

I created `entries.csv` with a single column of 100 randomly generated words. Including the header row, this file has 101 lines. Then I compiled this test document using the Linux `time` command:

```
time pdflatex test.tex
```

This produced:

```
real   0m0.177s
user   0m0.163s
sys    0m0.012s
```

With `verbose` mode switched on this changed to:

```
real    0m0.184s
user    0m0.163s
sys     0m0.018s
```

Then I retried with 10 columns and 100 rows (plus the header row) and the results were:

`verbose` off:

```
real    0m1.072s
user    0m1.059s
sys     0m0.012s
```

`verbose` on:

```
real    0m1.121s
user    0m1.100s
sys     0m0.014s
```

Then again with 10 columns and 10,000 rows (plus the header row):

`verbose` off:

```
real    1m44.484s
user    1m44.488s
sys     0m0.017s
```

`verbose` on:

```
real    1m47.569s
user    1m47.460s
sys     0m0.064s
```

So switching off the `verbose` mode can shave off a few seconds, but a far more significant improvement can be made by making TeX only set the contents of the token register *once* rather than repeatedly resetting it, and that can be done using [`datatooltk`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatooltk) before compiling the document. This is a Java application that can rapidly load and sort data loaded from CSV, XLS or ODS files or imported from a MySQL database.

Now

```
time datatooltk --csv entries.csv --output entries.dbtex
```

produces:

```
real    0m0.453s
user    0m0.826s
sys     0m0.038s
```

The test document only requires a minor modification:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddbtex{\entriesdb}{entries.dbtex}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

(The data can now be referenced in commands such as `\DTLforeach` using the first argument of `\DTLloaddbtex`, `\entriesdb` in this case.)

Now the compile time is:

```
real    0m0.180s
user    0m0.160s
sys     0m0.018s
```

Another way of speeding up the document compilation time is to make sure you use the read-only `\DTLforeach*` if you want to iterate through the data without modifying it.

For example, using the read-write (unstarred) version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddbtex{\entriesdb}{entries.dbtex}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach{\entriesdb}{}{}

\end{document}
```

This takes:

```
real    0m11.000s
user    0m10.983s
sys     0m0.016s
```

Using the read-only (starred version):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddbtex{\entriesdb}{entries.dbtex}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{\entriesdb}{}{}

\end{document}
```

This takes:

```
real    0m1.541s
user    0m1.527s
sys     0m0.012s
```

In summary, to speed up loading data with `datatool`:

1. Make sure you have at least version 2.0 (although that's now 6 years old).
2. Use `datatooltk` to first parse the data (and, if required, sort or filter it) and create a file that sets up the internal macros and registers that are used by `datatool` to store the data.

Pros and Cons of `datatooltk` verses `\DTLloaddb`:

1. With `\DTLloaddb` any LaTeX commands within the CSV file need a single backslash. With `datatoolktk` a double backslash is required.
2. `\DTLloaddb` is much slower than `datatooltk`.
3. `\DTLloaddb` can't load CSV files where an entry contains a line break, but `datatooltk` can.
4. `\DTLloaddb` can only load text files (comma-separated, tab-separated, etc), `datatooltk` can also load XLS, ODS and pull data from MySQL.