# Datatool Long Compilation Time without sorting

Tags: datatool, database

Hi this is my first time writing on the forum so please let me know if I do anything wrong.

Here is my problematic. I was wandering if I could use LaTeX to help me generate automatically grades reports. The idea is that I would have only to modify one template and LaTeX could generate, using a for loop, 30 reports in the same PDF file and all following the exact same appearance.

I'm using the `datatool` package simply to load a `.csv` file that is generated by Excel. Then I simply use

```
\DTLforeach*{Grade_CSV_file_label}{variables_assignment}{Create_grades_report}
```

Everything is working fine (from what I can tell) and the final results gives me 30 grades report for each 30 student.

Note that, I'm not using sorting function or creating any new database using `datatool`, I'm only reading a `.csv` file. My header is containing about 500 variables (it's a very tedious grade report).

My problem is that it take about 9 min to compile the document. This is causing other problems which I won't detail overhere.

Therefor my question is: does anyone have recommandations on how I could get this code running faster ?

Justifications: The reason why I want to use Excel is simply because I want friends (AKA teachers) to be able to simply enter grades into a template Excel file, which doesn't require any learning from them. Then if we want to modify the look of the report we simply have to change the LaTeX template and everybody is going to end with the exact same result.

Like I said everything works, the only problem is the compiling time.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Possibly related: [Document using datatool is slow to compile](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225438/document-using-datatool-is-slow-to-compile).